# OpenText action in Blueprism Excel object doesnt work anymore with Office365

Tags: excel, vba, office365, interop, blueprism

I have developed a custom action in Blueprism to perform the Workbooks.OpenText method.
This action was functional with Excel 2013.  But with the change to Office 365 the action is not working anymore; although the same code keeps working perfectly in a macro. No error is thrown, but the text file is opened in excel as default, ignoring the method and its parameter. The Blueprism Excel object  depends on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll and its code stages are written in VBA.

Find the code of the object attached below:

```
name = GetInstance(handle).Workbooks.Open(filename).Name
Dim wb as Object = GetInstance(handle).Workbooks
'Origin value = 65001
'num value Datatype=2
wb.OpenText(filename,Origin,1,num,,,True,,)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why is num=2? Try setting it to 1

Comment: num is the parameter for the DataType that specifies the column format of the data in the file. It was working previously regardless the value of num.